# Aurelia - App Initialization - Temporary Disable Property Change Notifications

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, aurelia

i have an SPA designed using features (collection of components).. each component exposes bindable properties and some observable properties for inner state management.. the feature at the top level also exposes bindable properties that are used in implementation views to render out specific funcitonalities.. each feature has data dependencies that pull from APIs and some features depend on each other for values that are bound after data loads...

the problem - how do I best handle app initialization when there's changed events firing from observable/bindable properties all through that initial load. my first thought is to find a way to disable all observable in a single place in code that i then turn on once everythign is loaded and ready to start reacting to cascading changes... does that exist in some low-level aurelia API? the only other alternative is to carefully and tediously map out all dependencies and sprinkle "if(!isInitialized) then exit" statements everywhere but that sounds horrible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on when you hydrate your components.
The docs here: http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/components#the-component-lifecycle say that if you do something to properties in bind() lifecycle handler - the change handlers would not be called.

Comment: I think that is a good work-around.. a bit hacky.. but it does say it only affects first-time changed handlers. thank you!